# Does php get updated id (auto_increment) in the same connection after an insert or do you have to reconnect?

Tags: php

I have the php:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("","","","");


$sql="INSERT INTO xxx (xxxx, yyyy, zzzz)
VALUES
('$_POST[A]','$B','$C')";


$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM xxx ORDER BY id DESC");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

Will this `$id` be the one before the inserted data or after?

```
$id = $row['id'];
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: this is just a snippet?

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you are wide open to attack.  You are fundamentally querying your database incorrectly.  I'm letting you know before you go down the road of building an entire application this way, leaving you out in the open.  It's not as if someone has to manually target your site... there are automated bots very good at finding injection attacks these days.  Within hours of putting up code like this, you can bet something will find it.

Comment: OK so I have used variables in statements like that for months and IM fine, how should I do this properly to avoid future attacks

Comment: Well you have official scared the s**t out of me! I do love hackers!

Comment: @LagMaster I have just been taught about it. Bare with me I am really bad at explaining. So I will just give you a basic example. If you have a form say. And you are submitting text that the user puts in the form to your database. You have to do something like this:`INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('$_POST[bar]')`. If the user then puts something like like this: `ABC')` into the form they can close what they are inserting. So then they can add more code like another mysql query into the php where they can add or view anything on your database. I hope that explains it okay.

Comment: What I would do to prevent it is to before the `'$_POST[bar]'` is inserted, strip the user from being able to put characters like `'` and `)` into the form @Brad Is that an okay explanation?

Comment: by doing something like this: `stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['bar']));`

Comment: @LagMaster I am worried that my last comment is utter rubbish. So don't use it. I think it probably just helps a little bit but is not 100% secure. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I wish that it was an official question! Haha I have never answered one before!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-increments work regardless of connection.  If you had 1,000 clients connected all inserting simultaneously, the auto-increment ID is guaranteed to be incremented as you would expect.  It's all nice and atomic like that.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood my question. I have just tested it and if I put `echo $id;` before `mysqli_close($con);` It will echo the id of the id before the php page was 'opened'

Comment: I needed to put this  `if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }` before `$id = $row['id'];
mysqli_close($con);
php`

Answer (score 0):

It will be the one after as you are retrieving it after, no reconnect needed.

PLEASE NOTE: if another client updates the information then the results will be incorrect.

Comment: This isn't true.  Other clients could insert before the select is finished.

Comment: Ok but thats not what his question is about.  The question has nothing todo with other clients

Comment: If an answer contains wrong information it should be downvoted.  Fix your answer, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: @Brad finally fixed it I believe

Answer (score 0):

Php provides a last insert id function. The auto increment id created is sent in the response packet from mysql so no need to query for the last id like you are doing.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: I am posting it into another table that is why I am querying it!

Comment: You mean copying the id over? What does posting to another table mean? Also your example shows inserting into one table then querying that table.

Comment: Sorry do you know id this will work? `$resulty = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT max(idnumber) FROM users WHERE username =='$name'");`

Comment: If you have duplicate usernames that is not guaranteed to work but it is likely to work for you is my guess

Comment: @Maximilian You can't guarantee that the largest ID is the one you just inserted.  You must check for the last inserted id, and by this connection.

Comment: I am getting this error! Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

try using below code

```
$qry= "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS insert_id";

$c = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry);
echo $c['insert_id'];
```